# Negative Training Image Examples for CNN

Tags: image, networking, machine-learning, classification, convolution

I am using the Caffe framework for CNN training. My aim is to perform simple object recognition for a few basic object categories. Since pretrained networks are not an alternative for my proposed usage I prepared an own training- and testset with about 1000 images for each of 2 classes (say chairs and cars).

The results are quite good. If I present an yet unseen image of a chair it is likely classified as such, same for a car image. My problem is that the results on miscellaneous images that do not show any of these classes often shows a very high confidence (=1) for one random class (which is not surprising regarding the onesided training data but a problem for my application). I thought about different solutions:

1) Adding a third class with also about 1000 negative examples that shows any objects except a chair and a car.

2) Adding more object categories in general, just to let the network classify other objects as such and not any more as a chair or car (of course this would require much effort). Maybe also the broader prediction results would show a more uniform distribution at negative images, allowing to evaluate the target objects presence based on a threshold?

Because it was not much time-consuming to grab random images as negative examples from the internet, I already tested my first solution with about 1200 negative examples. It helped, but the problem remains, perhaps because it were just too few? My concern is that if I increment the number of negative examples, the imbalance of the number of examples for each class leads to less accurate detection of the original classes.
After some research I found one person with a similar problem, but there was no solution:
[Convolutional Neural Networks with Caffe and NEGATIVE IMAGES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288156/convolutional-neural-networks-with-caffe-and-negative-images)

My question is: Has anyone had the same problem and knows how to deal with it? What way would you recommend, adding more negative examples or more object categories or do you have any other recommendation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not unique to Caffe or ConvNets. Any Machine Learning technique runs this risk. In the end, all classifiers take a vector in some input space (usually very high-dimensional), which means they partition that input space. You've given examples of two partitions, which helps to estimate the boundary between the two, but only that boundary. Both partitions have very, very large boundaries, precisely because the input space is so high-dimensional.

ConvNets do try to tackle the high-dimensionality of image data by having fairly small convolution kernels. Realistic negative data helps in training those, and the label wouldn't really matter. You could even use the input image as goal (i.e. train it as an autoencoder) when training the convolution kernels.

One general reason why you don't want to lump all counterexamples is because they may be too varied. If you have a class A with some feature value from the range [-1,+1] on some scale, with counterexamples B [-2,-1] and C [+1,+2], lumping B and C together creates a range [-2,+2] for counterexamples which overlaps the real real range. Given enough data and powerful enough classifiers, this is not fatal, but for instance an SVM can fail badly on this.